# Substring with grokPattern

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

With this example data

`GigabitEthernet102/0/0/28 = TLU-46356_CAR_ONE_RIVERO_AUTO_CENTER_PRINCIPAL Traffic (SNMP Traffic) Down  (The interface is disconnected: ifOperStatus=down (2) (code: PE058))`

Im try to get a substring ever that found "TLU" pattern and create a new field like this "TLU-46356"

Im use a grok pattern like this

`if ([logMessage] =~ /TLU-/){ grok { match => { "logMessage" => 'TLU=(?<TLU>[0-9a-fx]{8})' } }`

But don´t work and the result is "grokparsefailure"

Any idea, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested your example in Grok Debugger in Kibana and this works for me

```
(?<TLU>[0-9a-fx]{5})
```

For some reason `TLU=` in the beginning is not working, but grok will pick up named capture groups anyways, so even without it you'll get field called `TLU`.

The other part of the problem is that you're trying to match 8 characters from `0` to `9`, from `a` to `f` or `x`, but in your example number after `TLU-` is only 5 characters long. So either the logs have variable number of characters which you didn't mention and you should use something like `{n, m}` to define length of the string you want to capture. Or you can just say `*` and terminate it with `_` like this

```
(?<TLU>[0-9a-fx]*)_
```

If there's anything I'm missing please update the questions with additional data and let me know., good luck!